# Difference Between Load Balancing and Load Balancer

Tags: load-balancing, definition

I need to know the difference between a load balancer and load balancing.

Comment: The question lacks detail. Add some more detail explaining the context on which the question is asked(like in a parallel and distributed programming context or multiprocessor context ).

Comment: Hi Gam, Can you differentiate between the load balancer and load balancing. Where it will play a major role.

Comment: This question belongs on [English Language](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Load balancing** is the functionality provided by a **Load balancer** :).

In software architecture, a load balancer proxies client requests to a pool of application server, using an algorithm, with the objective of balancing the load of client requests evenly across the pool

Answer (score 4):

Load balancing refers to efficiently distributing incoming network traffic across a group of backend servers, also known as a server farm or server pool.

A load balancer acts as the “traffic cop” sitting in front of your servers and routing client requests across all servers capable of fulfilling those requests in a manner that maximizes speed and capacity utilization and ensures that no one server is overworked, which could degrade performance. If a single server goes down, the load balancer redirects traffic to the remaining online servers. When a new server is added to the server group, the load balancer automatically starts to send requests to it.

refer - https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/load-balancing/

Answer (score 2):

Load Balancing helps spread incoming request traffic across cluster of servers. If a server is not availble to take a request, load balancer passes this request to another server.

Load Balancer in turn are the ones which achieve above, they could come in between :-

1. User - webserver
2. Webserver - internal application servers
3. Internal servers - database servers
4. Application servers - cache servers

Different types of Load Balancers:

1. Smart Client - Adding load balance achievability by It is a client which takes a pool of service hosts and balances load across them, detects downed hosts and avoids sending requests their way.
2. Hardware Load Balancer - Buy your own dedicated high performance server eg. Citrix NetScaler.
3. Software Load Balancer - Buy a software load balancer to overcome all the pain of building your own smart client or if you not ready spending on dedicated server. Cost effective than above two is buying a software load balancer eg. VmWare, HAProxy etc

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge both are same but you can say that the load balancer is the device used for balancing the traffic as per the availability of the server and load balancing is nothing but theoretical explanation for how to achieve this. 
Please correct me if I'm wrong!